# Looking for a free, non-email-oriented alternative to gnupg for bulk encryption/decryption of individual files

Tags: encryption

I want to implement a system for bulk-encrypting individual files (as opposed to entire disks), to run on Linux, and I would like to use a free, open-source tool to do this.

My first thought was to use `gnupg` for this, but after reading more about it I find that its design is too strongly geared towards the use-case of encrypting/decrypting emails, which is very different from the use-case I have in mind.  As a result, as I read the documentation, I keep finding myself reading about considerations that are utterly irrelevant (e.g. web of trust, etc.) to what I want to do, and conversely, being unable to find information about the things I do want to do.

This is a clear sign that `gnupg`, whatever its merits for what it was designed to do, is just not the right tool for *my* problem.

What would be more a more appropriate tool?

My main requirements are it be open source, that it is available for Linux, and that it can be used to implement an unsupervised (i.e. non-interactive) encryption/decryption pipeline.  In other words, I am looking for something I can write programs with, not something I use interactively, since the goal is to use the program to encrypt thousands of individual files.

Comment: I wouldn't totally ignore gnupg. True, it's geared towards email, but you can still use it to encrypt your files.Read up on the -symmetric option.

Comment: @Ring: I am aware of the -symmetric option for gpg, but still I find that the tool is designed entirely around the problem of encrypting email communication, which means that using it for what I want to do turns out to be cutting against the grain, essentially fighting with the tool all the time; it gets tiring after a while.

Comment: Some creative bash scripting would let you just feed input files and get back encrypted files, though. Or you could use the API. Good luck however you go.